# What is causing the double request in the UpdatePanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, request, updatepanel, abort

In the master page for all page buttons:

```
findButton.Attributes.Add( "onclick", @" $(""#" + findButton.ClientID + @""").val(""Processing..."").attr(""disabled"",""disabled"");" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference( findButton, null ) + ";" );
```

The page has:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BindEvents() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
           ... prepare jquery ui combo boxes ...
         });
     }
</script>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPrint" />
        </Triggers>

        <ContentTemplate>
            <script type="text/javascript">Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);</script>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMainButtons" runat="server" Visible="true">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" Text="Find" OnClick="btnFind_OnClick" />
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClick="btnPrint_OnClick" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>

            ... other user controls ...
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And there is no AutoPostBack set. Find button is rendered as:

```
<input id="ctl00_ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_PlaceHolder_btnFind" type="submit" onclick=" $("#ctl00_ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_PlaceHolder_btnFind").val("Processing...").attr("disabled","disabled");__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$PlaceHolder$btnFind','');" value="Find" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$PlaceHolder$btnFind">
```

Firebug in Firefox shows double request send by clicking find button - second request succeeds, but what causes first one request to be sent?

Comment: I've check it in chrome and it works good - one request is send. However, you don't need __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainPlaceHolder$PlaceHolder$btnFind',''); part on btnFind cuz buttons with type submit will always cause postback. Always. So it doesn't matter you didn't add AutoPostback=true cause button will postback by default. If you click on printbtn it shows only one request in firebug?

Comment: well, my initial though also was the same - __doPostBack isn't needed (generated by the GetPostBackEventReference), however without it search event handler isn't invoked in postback - __EVENTTARGET is empty. btnPrint response is ok - generated pdf.

Comment: And what if you remove js from btnFind and add another postbacktrigger like this: <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFind" />? Does it work that way?